# fortran interface of SUNDIALS-CVODE is broken?

Tags: fortran

I was trying to use SUNDIALS-CVODE in a fortran program. But `fcvmalloc()` always returns error flag.

The fortran sample program included in the sundials package does not work either.
It has the same problem in `fcvmalloc()`.
But the c sample works well.

I have tried the package from apt as well as the locally compiled one, on both ubuntu and debian sid. None of the combination works and they just have the same problem in `fcvmalloc()`.

Thank you for having a look at this problem and the following is a reduced test case.

```
program test
  integer*4,parameter::nEq=2
  integer ier
  integer*4 ipar(1),iout(25)
  double precision rpar(1),rout(10)
  double precision t,dt,u(nEq)

  t=0d0
  u=[1d0,2d0]
  call fnvinits(1,nEq,ier)
  call fcvmalloc(t,u,1,1,1,1d-5,1d-5,iout,rout,ipar,rpar,ier)
  call fcvspgmr(0,1,50,0d0,ier)
  dt=1d-1
  do i=1,10
    call fcvode(t+dt,t,u,1,ier)
    write(*,*),t,u
  end do
  call fcvfree()
end program

subroutine fcvfun(t,u,du,ipar,rpar,ier)
  double precision t
  double precision u(*)
  double precision du(*)
  integer ipar(*)
  double precision rpar(*)
  integer ier

  du(1)=-0.5d0*u(1)
  du(2)=-3d0*u(2)
  ier=0
end subroutine
```

Comment: Did fvinits() complete successfully?  The documentation says fcvmalloc() will print diagnostic information to the terminal in case of failure - what are you seeing?

Comment: `fnvinits` returns good flag. `fcvmalloc()` says `[CVODE ERROR]  CVodeInit
  A memory request failed.`@WaywiserTundish

Answer (score 0):

Try using variable names for meth, itmeth, iatol, rtol, and atol instead of numeric values; that can cause problems when calling C library routines from Fortran.  Also make sure you built cvcode as double or extended precision and not single.

Comment: unfortunately it does not help. The result is the same.@WaywiserTundish

Comment: OK, the documentation says iout is a 21-element integer array and rout is a 6-element real array.  Your code has them dimensioned slightly larger.  Try changing those array sizes.  If that doesn't work, it may be time to break out the debugger.

Comment: The old version used 21/6. But the latest version uses 25/10. Thank you for having a look at this anyway.@WaywiserTundish

Answer (score 0):

In case of modern fortran you may use iso_c_binding and declare your parameters and variables compatible with C types in fcvode.h header file
i.e.

```
  integer(c_long ),parameter::nEq=2
  integer(c_int ) ier
  integer(c_long ) ipar(1),iout(21)
  real(c_double ) rpar(1),rout(10)
  real(c_double ) t,dt,u(nEq)
```

Comment: It is quite possible, that the problem is in the `long`'s that are now 8 bytes and not 4 as the examples assumed. Make the answer better explain why to do this and I will vote it up. (I didn't find the Fortran interface anywhere to be sure.)

Comment: Indeed, fortran interface docs in sundials are not perfect. However for fcvode  there are some docs explaining type definitions for specific function parameters: http://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/documentation/cv_guide/node6.html